# Why using next_page_token of google places API returning same results as of 1st page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I want places information from google places so I used "nearbysearch" API.
But it is only returning 1st 20 place information. So I used next_page_token to get places information which is on 2nd page but still it is returning information of places which are already there on 1st page.

```
  response=HTTParty.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+params[:place][:latitude]+","+params[:place][:longitude]+"&radius="+params[:place][:radius]+"&types="+params[:place][:type]+"&key=AIzaSyAD6Vgkz7vo-nZLZp-xeNoPchOr7RepWEU")  

  receipt=JSON.parse(response.body)   

  @next_page_token=receipt['next_page_token']
  response2=HTTParty.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+params[:place][:latitude]+","+params[:place][:longitude]+"&radius="+params[:place][:radius]+"&pagetoken=#{@next_page_token}&types="+params[:place][:type]+"&key=AIzaSyAD6Vgkz7vo-nZLZp-xeNoPchOr7RepWEU")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because both of these is true:

1. The `&pagetoken=` parameter of your request **doesn't contain a valid page token** (perhaps there is no second page of results, so it's just an empty string?).  This is your main problem.  Also,
2. Your second request repeats all the parameters, even though you don't need to with a page token.  The original request + an invalid `pagetoken=` is treated like the original request, as you've noticed :)

So you should:

1. manually verify that `@next_page_token` holds what you expect and fix what that reveals.  E.g. at the least you should add logic to deal with the case where the response doesn't have a `next_page_token`, and
2. change the second request to omit all parameters other than `key` and `pagetoken`, so that the unnecessary parameters don't mask your main bug.